# How to set default locale for Vaadin Flow (13/14) to German

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

is there something like?:

```
public static final Locale APP_LOCALE = Locale.GERMAN;
```

Operating system and browser locale are all in German but Vaadin UI DatePicker and Core-Buttons are still English

Translation or Internationalization is not intended.

HTML-Source is show correct;

```
<!doctype html><html lang="de">
```

Resources I found are all very old and do not work for Vaadin Flow

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the magic is done with the I18NProvider. You should implement this interface and activate it. In a component get the translations with getTranslation(..). For detailed examples read the i18n tutorial : https://vaadin.com/tutorials/i18n
or ping me ;)